# For Mac - How to Rename File to Folder name plus a number thus making the files sequential

Tags: macos, applescript, rename

Like my title asks how can I set a folder up to rename a new file to its name plus a sequential number. ie. Folder Name - `Cats Palying` New File Name - `Fluffy.jpg`. When I add Fluffy.jpg to the folder it would be renamed to `Cats Playing000001.jpg` next on would be "Cats `Playing000002.jpg`.

In my research, I found this answer but not sure how to change it to my application. Placing the following script into folder actions:

```
on adding folder items to the target_folder after receiving these_items
    tell application "Finder"
       set all_images to every item of the target_folder as list
       repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_items --iterates through all the items you dropped in the folder
          set this_image to item i of these_items --the current image
          set the name of this_image to "image" & (i + the count of all_images) as string --renames the image based on the number of images already in the folder
       end repeat
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: your question becomes more clear if you format the code as code. You can do that by either using backticks or by indenting each line with 4 spaces

Comment: This kind of script will never work as a folder action. At the moment a file is renamed in the hot folder the folder action is triggered again and you''ll run into an infinite loop.

Comment: Rather than running this way, which as @vadian says is doomed to failure, you might consider having a script on your desktop that you drag and drop a folder full of files onto and it then works out the folder name and renames the files contained within according to your needs...

Comment: Mark Setchell that seems like a great idea except I have no clue where to even begin to create that. Are there any programs out there that do this that you know of?